# Azure Networking ActiveFTP issue

Tags: azure, networking, ftp, azure-virtual-machine, ftp-client

We have recently moved our server onto Azure. It runs our point-of-sale system and uploads a few files via FTP to our webserver which then gets parsed and products are created.

The point of sale software developers have a bunch of batch files that run FTP.exe which unfortunately doesn't support passive file transfers(regardless of what you read - quote pasv & literal pasv don't work). So we are stuck using active transfers, unfortunately this doesn't suit Azure very well.

The server is using ports 10090 - 10100 for active connections (I have created a rule in the NSG to allow 10090-10100 in) but unfortunately this isn't working at all.

I'm in the process of trying to convince the developers to rewrite using WinSCP so that we can just use passive transfers, but otherwise I've been searching for another solution, and so far nothing has worked.

I know it's not an issue in the OS as I've turned off Windows Firewall & still no luck.

Any help or suggestions with this problem is greatly appreciated.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The server is using ports 10090 - 10100 for active connections (I have
>   created a rule in the NSG to allow 10090-10100 in) but unfortunately
>   this isn't working at all.

This is a by design behavior, because the VM's NSG inbount rules have no entries about the random unprivileged ports.

In active mode FTP the client connects from **a random unprivileged port** (N > 1023) to the FTP server's command port, port 21. Then, the client starts listening to port N+1 and sends the FTP command PORT N+1 to the FTP server. The server will then connect back to the client's specified data port from its local data port, which is port 20.

Here is the connection appears as follows:

[image]

For test, I had create 2 VMs (turn off windows firewall) in the same Vnet, and setup FTP on VM1, then use VM2 (disable use passive FTP) to access FTP, it works. Because VM1 and VM2 can connect with each other, and in the same Vnet the NSG does't work for internal network traffic.

So, in this case, active FTP isn't working because the server can't initiate a connection to the client. Maybe the most secure method is passive mode FTP.

Comment: Thanks ,
It's a pain because there is custom software that uses active FTP that the developers don't really want to change.
But they will be forced to change it now I guess.
Can't do much about it.
Thanks for your help with this.